# Remove CarouselView WhiteSpace

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel

I'm trying to implement a `CarouselView` to display a set of images on my app. Apparently, I can't remove the Whitespace at the Bottom of the `CarouselView` no matter what combinations I tried.

I've placed `BackgroundColor` property for `CarouselView` [Red], `Grid`[Green] (inside DataTemplate), and `IndicatorView` [Blue] to see which of them is consuming the rest of the screen despite the lack of `StackLayout` and it seems that either `CarouselView` or `Grid` is causing the unwanted behaviour.

Here's my `XAML` Code with roughly nothing on the `ViewModel` but a Mock Database for the Image Collection:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*"
          RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,1*">
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
               Text="CarouselView Test"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="20"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Padding="10" />

        <CarouselView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="{Binding ScreenWidth}"
                      x:Name="TheCarousel"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSourceCollection}"
                      IndicatorView="indicatorView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto" BackgroundColor="Green" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding .}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>

        <IndicatorView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Blue"
                       x:Name="indicatorView"
                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       IndicatorSize="10"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="Black" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And here's a screenshot of my current build with the CarouselView/Grid consuming most of the Screen Space:

[image]

Comment: You need to assign some concrete height values, otherwise the carousel and grid will just take up all the available space.  Because the carousel contains an image that is dynamically loaded at runtime it has no idea how big it needs to be when it calculates its layout.

Answer (score 1):

`CarouselView` has some weird behaviors on size calculating,in your scenario the only way is get the height it(template) needs in code(viewmodel), and bind it to the `HeightRequest` on `CarouselView` .

#### Xaml

```
 <CarouselView HeightRequest="{Binding xxx}"
```

#### View model

```
public double xxx { 
   get 
   {
      // calculate the height according to the width by ratio
      return height;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Then `CarouselView ` will remove the unwanted space and IndicatorView will stick to it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set [Space between rows and columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#space-between-rows-and-columns) to Zero if you want to make your `indicatorView` stick to your `CarouselView`

Comment: Well the same thing happens when i'm using `StackLayout` so i'm not sure setting that property would do any difference.

Comment: If so then you need to go with `AbsoluteLayout` and make it floating in front of your `CarouselView`

Comment: StackLayout has a default spacing of 6.  From your question it is unclear if you mean the white space above the indidcator view or something else

Answer (score 0):

So what actually worked for me.
I set Grid Row Definition to ex.(300) and then Carousel Height Request to 350.

I'm setting Image Width based on Screen Width, but I tried it Manually ex (400) and still worked, don't get confused.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="300">
    <CarouselView x:Name="carouselView"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding HomeCarousel}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame HasShadow="False"
                           CornerRadius="0"
                           Margin="0"                
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           HeightRequest="350">
                        <SwipeView>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"                                 
                                   Aspect="AspectFill"
                                   WidthRequest="{DynamicResource FullScreenWidth}"                         
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        </SwipeView>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</Grid>
```